# Change :before when :hover over main DIV?

Tags: html, css

I have a div that looks like a speech bubble. The main div is the bubble and the :before is the arrow. What I want to do, is when you rollover `:hover` the DIV in CSS, it will also change the `:before`.

Here's my code:

```css
.sidebar_image_box_newsfeed_user_info_comments { 
    color: #ffffff; 
    background-color: #2f2f2e;
    text-decoration: none; 
    -webkit-transition-property: background-color, color, text-decoration; 
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s, 0.5s, 0.5s; 
}

.sidebar_image_box_newsfeed_user_info_comments:hover { 
    background-color: #3b3b3b; 
    color: #f3f3f3; 
    text-decoration: underline; 
}

.sidebar_image_box_newsfeed_user_info_comments:before { 
    content:""; position:absolute;
    bottom:-6px; right:0;
    border-width:0 0 6px 6px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:transparent #2f2f2e;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition-property: background-color, color, text-decoration;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s, 0.5s, 0.5s;
}
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
.sidebar_image_box_newsfeed_user_info_comments:hover:before {
   content: "I am new";
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/Kr8e8/).

Comment: Expanding on alex's answer, you can replace "I am new" with url(image) for an image

Comment: thats what I was looking for, thanks!